# Copy/Clone dynamic object?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have a dynamic object by calling dapper.Query(...).

I'd like to add a member during runtime but I can't. I know of ExpandoObject but it doesn't take in a constructor to copy all the members.

Is there a way I can copy all the members of a dynamic object then add a field or two like i wanted?

-edit- solved via workaround. I added a dummy column in sql (`select ..., '' [MyFieldName]`) then i had no problems assigning MyFieldName to my string value.

Comment: Pls could you show some code you tried?

Comment: @CuongLe: What code? ExpandoObject doesnt take a constructor to clone and Query is in the well known dapper.net

Comment: Firstly why do you need to use a dynamic? can't you make data structure that represents the data elements you've selected from the data base?

Comment: @DavidHughes: Why make a data structure when all I need is one extra field? I found a solution though

Comment: Because you are moving problems from compile-time to run-time with dynamic.

Comment: @DavidHughes: But by doing that I have two places to update my data  (query and class) when i don't need to

Comment: You should post your answer as an actual answer below the question!

Answer (score 0):

solved via workaround. I added a dummy column in sql (`select ..., '' [MyFieldName]`) then i had no problems assigning MyFieldName to my string value.